# Using open and i2c in C++

Tags: c++, linux, ioctl, i2c

I've realized that `open()` and `ioctl()` does not work inside a cpp object. I am able to do the operation if it is called inside my `main()` function, but NOT when inside any of my classes. I have a object that is running in my main loop that has another object that makes the file system calls.

So basically when in the main loop it can open (I get a 3  for the pointer and the `ioctl` is successful). But when I do it in object it returns 0 for open (which isn't supposedly an error) and the ioctl fails.

I know I can't use the `ios::` iostream options because they don't work with `ioctl`. How can I make regular ioctl work inside a cpp object?

```
int add=0x4b;
int i2c_bus;

if(( i2c_bus = open( "/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR )) < 0 )
{
    printf("Unable to open file /dev/i2c-0.\n");
}

if( ioctl( i2c_bus, I2C_SLAVE, add ) < 0 )
{
    printf("Open chip %d FAILED file %d\n",add, i2c_bus);
    return -1;
}
else 
{
    printf("Open chip %d Succeeded file %d\n\n",add, i2c_bus);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `open` and `ioctl` play nicely with C++, the problem is in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You've assigned the result of `open` to `i2c_bus`, but you're using `fd` in the ioctl. Did you change the variable names when you moved from `main`?

Comment: Sorry, this example was patched together, but yes I always use the same file pointer. I am just trying 100 different ways since nothing works.

Comment: There's nothing about C++ that by itself would cause this problem. Is you application also multi-threaded? Another possibility is that something in your headers is redefining `open`, so that the `open` you are calling is not the system call you expect it to be. There isn't an `open` method in your class, is there? After that there's the possibility of really obscure linking problems.